# Make the text field for mod flags resizable

Tags: feature-request, design, flags, flag-dialog

The text field for mod flags (for both posts and comments) is too small for the amount of text that can be written in it and it would be useful to have it be resizable (at least the height).

This is how it looks right now for posts (its height is even smaller than the one for comments):

[image: Posts mod flags text field]

And this is the one for comments (slightly better but still too small):

[image: Comments mod flag text field]

Can you please make the text field resizable so that it's easier to spot mistakes before submitting?

Comment: Yeah, for some very odd reason they explicitly disable resize for textarea in the main CSS. They added exception to comments textarea at some point, but all the rest won't have resize option. Guess they better hire UX expert. If the browser let you do something, disabling it outright is just wrong IMO and bad experience.